# How to disable default logging in JBoss AS7?

Tags: logging, jboss7.x

I want to disable default JBoss AS7 logging as we are using external logging framework, can anyone tell me how can we do that?

Comment: Could you explain what you're after a bit more? Disabling logging is easy, but that would disable all logging from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Information about the logging subsystem is explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-rootlogger) in the JBoss Wiki.

But basically you should be able to remove in your standalone.xml the handlers and set the logging level to OFF:

```
<root-logger>
    <level name="OFF"/>
</root-logger>
```